# How to pass mocked interface object to the main class c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, moq

I have the below code :

```
    public interface Iinterface
    {
        Task<bool> RetrieveFromDataBase();
    }
    public class Class1 : Iinterface
    {
        public async Task<bool> RetrieveFromDataBase()
        {
            //do something
            return true;
        }
    }
    public class AnotherClass
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();       
        public AnotherClass(Class1 obj)
        {
           c = obj;
        }
        public async Task<bool> ExecuteData()
        {
            var result = await c.RetrieveFromDataBase();
            if (result)
            {
                //do some calculation
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now, I'm trying to write test cases for `ExecuteData` method. In this method I need to bypass `RetrieveFromDataBase` method. So I'm trying to mock it. This is the below code I have written.

```
    [TestClass()]
    public class AnotherClassTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public async Task ExecuteDataTest()
        {
            Task<bool> retValue = RetrieveFromDataBaseMoq(); // this returns true 
            var moq = new Mock<Iinterface>();
            moq.Setup(x => x.RetrieveFromDataBase()).Returns(retValue);

            AnotherClass obj = new AnotherClass((Class1)moq.Object); // error thrown from here
            var result = await obj.ExecuteData();
            Assert.IsTrue(result);
        }
    }
```

The mocking which is done is successful, i.e it doesn't throw any error. The problem I'm facing here is when I pass this mocked object a parameter to the constructor, it is throwing error System.InvalidCastException :  Unable to cast object "Castle.Proxies.Iinterface" to type "Class1".

I know that it is not able to convert mocked interface to the concrete class type. But is there a way to rectify this error or pass the mocked object to the main class in anyway.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should declare variable `c` as an `Iinterface`. That's one of the advantages of using interfaces. You should dependend on the contract(interface) , instead of concrete implementations. Following that you are not coupled to concrete classes.

```
 public class AnotherClass
{
    Iinterface c; //I removed the default new since it will get assigned in constructor     

    public AnotherClass(Iinterface obj)
    {
       c = obj;
    }

    public async Task<bool> ExecuteData()
    {
        var result = await c.RetrieveFromDataBase();
        if (result)
        {
            //do some calculation
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

> The problem here I'm facing is, the class Class1 has some other methods and variables as well which are not declared in the interface.

You could do a composition inside Class1, and move the TInterface as a dependency inside Class1. Keep in mind that the interface is what you will get mocked in unit test

```
public class Class1 
{ 
    public TIinterface tinterface{get;private set;}
    public Class1(TIinterface interface)
    {
        tinterface= interface;
    }
}
public class YourCustomImplementation:TIinterface 
{
   public async Task<bool> RetrieveFromDataBase()
   {
        //do something
        return true;
   }
}



public class AnotherClass
{
    Class1 c = new Class1();       
    public AnotherClass(Class1 obj)
    {
       c = obj;
    }
    public async Task<bool> ExecuteData()
    {
        var result = await c.tinterface.RetrieveFromDataBase();
        if (result)
        {
            //do some calculation
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish , I could declaring c as Iinterface. The problem here I'm facing is, the class Class1  has some other methods and variables as well which are not declared in the interface. And these methods and variables are used in AnotherClass . So when I change it into interface, the class has so many compilation errors. This is an old code which was given to me to write testcases :(

Comment: @CrazyCoder That's arguably a _new question_

Comment: I'm just saying the problem I'm facing with the solution you have offered.Its not a new question.

Comment: If Class1 is doing too much things you are breaking single responsability concept. Could you split Class1  class in 2 different classes(or more) so you can inject them in constructor as different parameters? Also you can to make Class1 have inside a TInterface variable , and then use it in the call to the method  RetrieveFromDataBase

Comment: @Badulake Thanks a lot for this detailed explaination and code. But can you tell me in my test method, from where the error was thrown, should I pass the mocked interface object or convert to Class1 and pass it ?

Comment: The error was thrown because you cannot cast a TInterface object to a Class1 type( polymorfism work in the opposite way). In the other hand you will be able to cast a Class1 to a TIinerface cause it 's implementing it. You could mock the entire Class1 and you won't get any error, but i suspect that you don't want that...